# How to omit columns in a Schema.ini file?

Tags: vba, ms-access, schema, ini

I'm building an ini files to import a complex text file to a table in Access. How do you omit a column? My text file is fixed width but still had a separator column in between each column of data that I don't need.

Comment: Import all columns to a temp table and copy the required columns to another table.

Comment: ^^ This. Temporarily link the text file to access and run an import query with the columns needed. Once done, remove the linked file.